# Class of vectors with specific length

Tags: c++, class, vector, types

I'm trying to create de class of vectors of a specfic length from the STL vector.
That's my code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include<complex>


using namespace std;

template <class T, int N>
class KN : public vector<T> {

public:
KN(){T b=0;
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++){(*this).push_back(b);}}

KN(vector<T> a) { for (int i=0; i<N; i++){(*this).push_back(a[i]);}}     

KN & operator +(const KN & v){     
vector<T> sortie;
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {(sortie).push_back((*this)[i]+v[i]);}   
return KN(sortie);  };

friend int conj(const int& x)
{
   return(x);
 };

friend double conj(const double& x)
{
   return(x);
};

T & operator , (const KN & v){
T c();    
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    c=c+ (*this)[i] * conj(v[i]);
}    
return c;
};

KN & operator * (const T& e){

vector<T> sortie;     
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{       
  sortie.pusk_back((*this)[i]* e);     
}    
return KN(sortie);

};   

};
```

I'm testing  my functions with this main.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include<complex>
#include "ex3.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
KN<int,10> vint;
KN<int,10> vint2;

for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
{vint[i]=1;}

for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
{vint2[i]=2;}



for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
cout<<(vint +vint2)[i]<<endl;
cout<<(vint ,vint2)[i]<<endl;
cout<<(vint*2)[i]<<endl;
```

But I have all of these errors:

```
main3.cpp: In function `int main()':
main3.cpp:50: error: name lookup of `i' changed for new ISO `for' scoping
main3.cpp:48: error:   using obsolete binding at `i'
main3.cpp:50: error: invalid types `int[int]' for array subscript

ex3.hpp: In member function `KN<T, N>& KN<T, N>::operator+(const KN<T, N>&) [with T = int, int N = 10]':
main3.cpp:49:   instantiated from here
ex3.hpp:23: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'KN<int, 10>&' from a temporary of type 'KN<int, 10>'

ex3.hpp: In member function `T& KN<T, N>::operator,(const KN<T, N>&) [with T = int, int N = 10]':
main3.cpp:50:   instantiated from here
ex3.hpp:39: error: pointer to a function used in arithmetic
main3.cpp:50:   instantiated from here
ex3.hpp:39: error: assignment of function `T c() [with T = int, int N = 10]'
ex3.hpp:39: error: cannot convert `int (*)()' to `int ()()' in assignment
main3.cpp:50:   instantiated from here
ex3.hpp:41: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int (*)()'
ex3.hpp: In member function `KN<T, N>& KN<T, N>::operator*(const T&) [with T = int, int N = 10]':
main3.cpp:51:   instantiated from here
ex3.hpp:49: error: 'class std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' has no member named 'pusk_back'
main3.cpp:51:   instantiated from here
ex3.hpp:51: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'KN<int, 10>&' from a temporary of type 'KN<int, 10>'
```

Can anybody help me please? I don't no how to declared in a good way my functions...

Comment: If it was posible i would be happy if anybody tell me what's wrong with this function

    KN & operator +(const KN & v){     
    vector<T> & sortie;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {(sortie).push_back((*this)[i]+v[i]);}   
    return KN(sortie);  };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
cout<<(vint +vint2)[i]<<endl;
cout<<(vint ,vint2)[i]<<endl;
cout<<(vint*2)[i]<<endl;
```

You're missing your braces around the loop's statements.

---

```
KN(vector<T> a)
```

This is not how you declare a copy-from-vector constructor. You should use:

```
KN(const vector<T>& a)
```

---

And please, please, please find some other way to do this besides overloading `operator,`. You're not even doing it right: you need to return a temporary, not modify the object in place and return a reference to it.

Your code is loaded with typos as well. Please clean this up and do a better job of explaining just what you're trying to do here.

---

> If it was posible i would be happy if anybody tell me what's wrong with this function

```
KN & operator +(const KN & v) {     
    vector<T> sortie;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        (sortie).push_back((*this)[i]+v[i]);
    }   
    return KN(sortie);
};
```

Lots of stuff. First, you're returning the wrong thing; you don't return a reference from +, you return an object. `1 + 1` gives you an `int`, not an `int&`. Second, you're creating a `vector<T>` when you want to return a `KN`. Just create a `KN` in the first place! Your return statement isn't typecasting, it's creating a new object from the vector. So many wasted operations here.

```
KN<T, N> operator +(const KN<T, N> & v) {     
    KN<T, N> result(*this);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        result[i] += v[i];
    }   
    return result;
};
```

---

Finally, if you want a fixed-length vector, you should use the [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) template from C++11 or [Boost::array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/array.html) from Boost if you don't have C++11.

Comment: OH! Thank you so much for your explanaitons.I've started to use c++ 2 months ago and i know very few things. Now I understand more. Thank you again

Comment: Actually I solved all the problems of my code. Thank you again! :)